# How to build csipsimple on windows?

Tags: android, windows, sip

I want to build CSipSimple latest version using eclipse on windows, but when i imported the svn-checkout folder of csipsimple in eclipse, it shows five projects imported in eclipse's project explorer intead of the CSipSimple project itself. I may either doing it in a wrong or missing some step.

Please guide me through the right steps to build CSipSimple on Windows!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The first thing is that you probably checked out too high first.
Use svn checkout http://csipsimple.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/CSipSimple/ csipsimple

Then second point, you probably missed the wiki page about how to build : http://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/wiki/HowToBuild

You'll also see that there is a mailing list (google group) for guys who wants to build the application. And your question was already asked.

My advise is to *NOT* use Windows. Real developers don't ;). Switch to linux, and you'll just have to follow steps of the wiki page then.

Else you'll have to adapt each step of the build process. But it means that you'll have to install on windows tools such as git, quilt, swig2.0 etc etc that are obvious to install on linux and may give you headache to install on windows.